# Gatsby Graphql issue when trying to connect at GraphCMS api

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, gatsby

i have an up and running api from GraphCMS.

i am building a small static website and want with Gatsby and i wanna take some data from GraphCMS with Graphql client (https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-request)

problem is that i am getting a `types.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL Error (Code: 200)` while doing the following:

My `index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import { GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request'
import Header from '../components/header'
import './index.css'

export default () =>
<div style={{ color: `tomato` }}>
<h1>Hello Gatsby!</h1>
<p>What a world.</p>
</div>




 const client = new GraphQLClient('my-endpoint', {
 headers: {
 Authorization: 'mytokenfromGraphCms',
 },
 })

 const query = `{
 allCurrentEvents{ 
 tip
 awayteam
 hometeam
 date
 }
 allPasteventses{
 tip
 }
 }`

 client.request(query).then(data => console.log(data))
```

any thoughts?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow read permissions for the fields you are querying? Or are you using a token? Can you actually post the error response you get from the request?